# ns: _o108malicious: invalid command name "_o108malicious" while executing "_o108malicious"

Tags: tcl, ns2

> I am simulating Wireless Sensor Network Using NS2.35 and I get an error
>   ns: _o108malicious: invalid command name "_o108malicious"
>   while executing "*o108malicious"
>   when i add $ns at 3.2 "[$node*($id) set ragent_]malicious"this line i get
>      this error.
>       set val(chan) Channel/WirelessChannel
>       set val(prop) Propagation/TwoRayGround
>       set val(netif) Phy/WirelessPhy
>       set val(mac) Mac/802_11
>       set val(ifq) Queue/DropTail/PriQueue
>       set val(ll) LL
>       set val(ant) Antenna/OmniAntenna
>       set val(ifqlen) 150
>       set val(nn) 25
>       set val(rp) AODV
>       set val(x) 800
>       set val(y) 500
>       set val(stop) 150

```
#-------Event scheduler object creation--------#

set ns              [new Simulator]
#used to schedule the events that are running at the same time
$ns use-scheduler Heap

#Creating trace file and nam file
set tracefd       [open aodv.tr w]
set namtrace      [open aodv.nam w]   
$ns trace-all $tracefd
$ns namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $val(x) $val(y)

# set up topography object
set topo       [new Topography]
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)
create-god $val(nn)

# configure the nodes
        $ns node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
                   -llType $val(ll) \
                   -macType $val(mac) \
                   -ifqType $val(ifq) \
                   -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
                   -antType $val(ant) \
                   -propType $val(prop) \
                   -phyType $val(netif) \
                   -channelType $val(chan) \
                   -topoInstance $topo \
                   -agentTrace ON \
                   -routerTrace ON \
                   -macTrace OFF \
                   -movementTrace ON


# node creation

      for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } {
            set node_($i) [$ns node] 
$node_($i) color "black" 
$node_($i) label Node$i   
      }
#initial location of nodes

for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} {incr i} {

$node_($i) set X_ [expr rand()*$val(x)]
$node_($i) set Y_ [expr rand()*$val(y)]
$node_($i) set Z_ 0

$node_($i) color "green"

}


for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} {incr i} {

$ns at 0.1 "$node_($i) color darkviolet"
$ns at 0.1 "$node_($i) label Node$i"

}

#generation of movements

$ns at 2.0 "$node_(0) setdest 20.0 10.0 0.0"
$ns at 5.0 "$node_(24) setdest 60.0 50.0 50.0"
$ns at 7.0 "$node_(2) setdest 120.0 100.0 50.0"
$ns at 0.0 "$node_(17) setdest 140.0 150.0 50.0"
$ns at 0.0 "$node_(20) setdest 160.0 180.0 50.0"
$ns at 12.0 "$node_(19) setdest 130.0 230.0 6.0"
$ns at 23.0 "$node_(5) setdest 40.0 165.0 9.0"
$ns at 20.0 "$node_(7) setdest 50.0 180.0 13.0"
$ns at 3.0 "$node_(4) setdest 80.0 156.0 5.0"
$ns at 6.0 "$node_(10) setdest 56.0 200.0 10.0"
$ns at 13.0 "$node_(15) setdest 88.0 20.0 45.0"
$ns at 6.0 "$node_(3) setdest 177.0 120.0 45.0"
$ns at 23.0 "$node_(1) setdest 140.0 70.0 20.0"


set fp2 [open "/opt/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/input.txt" r]
set filed [read $fp2]
puts $filed
set data [split $filed "\n"]
puts $data
foreach line2 $data {
set length2 [string length $line2]
if {$length2 != 0} {
lassign $line2 src dest
puts $src
set tcp1 [new Agent/TCP/Newreno]
$tcp1 set class_ 2
set sink1 [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns attach-agent $node_($src) $tcp1
$ns attach-agent $node_($dest) $sink1
$ns connect $tcp1 $sink1
set ftp1 [new Application/FTP]
$ftp1 attach-agent $tcp1
$ns at 3.0 "$node_($src) color brown"
$ns at 3.0 "$node_($dest) color brown"
$ns at 3.0 "$ftp1 start"
}
}
close $fp2



set fp1 [open "/opt/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/mali.txt" r]
set file_data [read $fp1]
set data1 [split $file_data "\n"]
foreach line $data1  {
set length1 [string length $line]
if {$length1 !=0} {
set id $line
$ns at 3.2 "[$node_($id) set ragent_]malicious"
$ns at 3.2 "$node_($id) color red"
$ns at 3.2 "$node_($id) label malicious"
}
}
close $fp1

# Define node initial position in nam
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} { incr i } {
# 20 defines the node size for nam
$ns initial_node_pos $node_($i) 20
}

# Telling nodes when the simulation ends
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } {
    $ns at $val(stop) "$node_($i) reset";
}
# ending nam and the simulation
$ns at $val(stop) "$ns nam-end-wireless $val(stop)"
$ns at $val(stop) "stop"
#$ns at 149.01 "puts \"end simulation\" ; $ns halt"
proc stop {} {
    global ns tracefd namtrace
    $ns flush-trace
    close $tracefd
    close $namtrace
exec nam aodv.nam &
exit 0
}

#$ns at 150.01 "puts \"end simulation\" ; $ns halt"

$ns run
enter code here 
input.txt
5   4
3   9
6   10
1   0
mali.txt
5
3
```

Comment: That looks like it is the actual name of an instance object (which would have been stored in a variable). The problem is probably that the object has been deleted before your script expected it to be.

Comment: K.Dhivyabarathi : If you want a solution → 1) Please edit your question to include the type of WSN. Mannasim? Leach? Other? ... 2) Please upload your simulation.tcl , and add a **shared** link to your question.

Comment: The traffic? files `input.txt` and `mali.txt` are missing. The  files can be uploaded to e.g. Dropbox or 'Google Drive'.

Comment: we already upload the input.txt and mali.txt file below the code.

Answer (score 0):

When the "set malicious" line `$ns at 3.2 "[$node_($id) set ragent_]malicious"` ... is edited to `$ns at 3.2 "[$node_($id) set ragent_] hacker"` ... then your files are working fairly OK :

```
$ ns235-malicious mal-wsn.tcl
num_nodes is set 25
warning: Please use -channel as shown in tcl/ex/wireless-mitf.tcl
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
5   4
3   9
6   10
1   0 

{5   4} {3   9} {6   10} {1   0 } {}
5
3
6
1
channel.cc:sendUp - Calc highestAntennaZ_ and distCST_
highestAntennaZ_ = 1.5,  distCST_ = 550.0
SORTING LISTS ...DONE!
ns: scheduler going backwards in time from 6.000000 to 0.000000.
```

1. The files aodv.nam 200.0kB, aodv.tr 184.0kB are created. `$ nam aodv.nam &` : OK animation and communication. `$ awk -f tess-Packets.awk aodv.tr` : OK, the output file "Packets-arrival-time.txt" has 338 lines.
2. Not quite stable. Can also end the simulation with

   `SORTING LISTS ...DONE !
   Direction for pkt-flow not specified; Sending pkt up the stack on default.`

... And NAM opens OK. The files are now: aodv.nam 328.0kB, aodv.tr 308.0kB .

3. Perfect. Ends with `SORTING LISTS ...DONE!`. Animation: Perfect. Files are aodv.nam **7.0** MB, aodv.tr **5.7** MB .
4. `Direction for pkt-flow not specified; Sending pkt up the stack on default.`
   `check_pktRTS:Invalid MAC Control subtype`

... Conclusion : You will have to run the file several times to get a perfect result. Can be 10 times if Ubuntu. 3 - 4 times if an rpm based OS.

---

Malicious build example https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/malicious%7Csort:date/ns-users/-3JfDWhN2fY/BiOwZuWSBwAJ  → 11/10/17.

Comment: Sir please send the your tcl file. I Didn't get the output.have some error.so please send the ns235-malicious mal-wsn.tcl file.

Comment: ? Are you quite sure you have an ns-2.35 built with `aodv-malicious_ns235.patch` ? ... The file `mal-wsn.tcl` is a copy of your above code. ( Without the surplus long text lines : path to input.txt, mali.txt ) Link to mal-wsn.tcl  https://www.dropbox.com/s/03vsxwybbpdom88/mal-wsn.tcl?dl=0

Comment: sir i didn't get the output.they show the splitobject error.

Comment: the error is 
SORTING LISTS ...DONE!
ns: _o108 hacker: 
    (_o108 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o108 cmd hacker"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o108" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"_o108 hacker"

Comment: If you follow the build example https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/malicious%7Csort:date/ns-users/-3JfDWhN2fY/BiOwZuWSBwAJ → 11/10/17, you will know the command `ns235-malicious [file].tcl` . Your errors indicate that the wrong executable `ns` is used. I.e. an 'ns' with no malicious. (No "hacker").